# Promise.all not working as expected ignoring unresolved promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I have this code

```
    onRemove = (fileId) => {
        this.setState({ removing: true });
        Promise.all([this.props.onRemove(fileId)])
            .then(() => {
                console.log('I execute after');
                this.setState({ removing: false });
            })
            .catch(() => {
                this.setState({ removing: false });
            });
    }
```

`onRemove` is triggered by `onClick` from my `jsx` code like this:

```
onClick={() => {this.onRemove(fileId);}}
```

For simplicity reasons, my `this.props.onRemove` looks like this:

```
    removeFile = (UUID) => {
        const sleep = milliseconds => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
        return sleep(1500).then(() => {
            console.log('I execute');
        });
    };
```

When I run my code, I get this in my console:

```
I execute after
I execute
```

Which I am of course assuming is wrong!

isn't `Promise.all` supposed to wait for all promises to resolve before executing what is in the `then` block?

What am I missing, been banging my head against a wall for a while now.

Update:

I added `return` to `removeFile` as comments suggested but the behaviour remains the same.

Comment: try `return sleep(1500).then(() => {` ( in `removeFile ` )

Comment: `Promise.all([this.props.onRemove(fileId)])` calls that `onRemove()` function *immediately*; if it's some sort of event handler that doesn't make sense. *edit* ^^ above comment might definitely help as the simplified version of the function you posted doesn't return anything.

Comment: you have no return value from removeFile, so it is in your case equivalent to having an asynchronous function resolving immediately with undefined value

Comment: Translating into English: Your `removeFile` doesn't return anything, so there's nothing for `Promise.all` to wait for.

Comment: I added some `returns` and I still get same behaviour

Comment: you added them in the wrong place tho, add return statement before the sleep

Comment: I updated `removeFile` again, still no luck!

Comment: I think that `setTimeout()` is launching it's own thread, and the promise is not aware of that thread.  I don't know _why_ you are using `setTimeout()` and I think that is your real problem, but I think you would need to make the promise wait for the `setTimeout()` callback function to be called before it returns, but `setTimeout()` doesn't give you a callback.

Comment: @ansielf `setTimeout() is launching it's own thread` -> nope, JS is single-threaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided seems to be working just fine.

```js
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    removing: false
  }
  
  onRemove = fileId => {
    this.setState({ removing: true });
    Promise.all([this.props.onRemove(fileId)]).then(() => {
      console.log('I execute after');
      this.setState({ removing: false });
    })
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({ removing: false });
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => { this.onRemove('fileId');}}>
        Remove File
      </button>
    );
  }
}

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const removeFile = UUID => {
    const sleep = milliseconds => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
      return sleep(1500).then(() => {console.log("I execute");});
  }
  
  return <ChildComponent onRemove={removeFile} />
};

ReactDOM.render(<ParentComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id='root'></div>
</body>
```